# Creating jumper leads from ethernet cables - connect multiple components

Tags: ethernet, wiring, pi-gpio

I've bought some crimpers and a dupont connection kit and I'm planning on reusing some old cat5 ethernet cables I have.

Is it reasonable to connect two devices to the RPi via the 8 wires in the cat5 cable?  For example connecting four jumpers to 4 GPIO pins on the RPi connecting to one device and the other four cables in the cat 5 cable to four other jumpers on the RPi connected to a second device?

This is attractive because it keeps the wiring (that will be visible) reasonably tidy but I'm not sure if this approach is technically appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do this all the time. Ethernet (Cat5) cable is twisted pair, which provides you with cross-talk protection.

Note that the longest run I've used is about 36", so you may have to do testing to ensure you're not receiving interference at long distances if that's what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Awesome thanks @stevieb. I'll have a run of about 1.5m I think

Answer (score 5):

Lots of folks do that.

You may need to add some small capacitors on long cable runs to reduce and RF interference that a long unshielded cable can pick up.